# Loop through a dictionary and list values and index of the values

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am trying to loop through a dictionary and return the values and corresponding index of the value.  So far, I am able to return the entire list.

```
cdict = {'ZS': [3,3,3,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,11,11,11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,3]}

for k, v in cdict.items():
    print (v)
```

I would like to be able to return the following:
3, 0
3, 1
3, 2
5, 3
...
3, 23.
Where 0,1,2,3 etc (in the second column) are the respective index positions of the values.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already shown that you can iterate over the dictionary. So what's left is to print the list with indexes. Python has a nice function for that called `enumerate`:

```
for (i, v) in enumerate([3,3,5]):
    print(v, i)

3 0
3 1
5 2
```

Enumerate turns any iteratable into pairs of index and value. So it doesn't just work for list but anything you can iterate.

Answer (score 2):

```
cdict = {'ZS': [3,3,3,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,11,11,11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,3]}

for k, v in cdict.items():
    for idx in range(len(v)):
        print('{}, {}'.format(v[idx], idx))
```

Comment: You're too fast, i was going to post the same

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Single-line solution:

```
a = list(map(lambda v: list(map(lambda x: print("{}, {}".format(*x[::-1])) or x[::-1], enumerate(v))), cdict.values()))
```

*bonus*: in `a` you could find the following list:
[[(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (11, 15), (11, 16), (11, 17), (11, 18), (1, 19), (1, 20), (1, 21), (1, 22), (3, 23)]]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what your after but this will print the item in the dict and the index:

```
cdict = {'ZS': [3,3,3,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,8,8,11,11,11,11,11,11,1,1,1,1,3]}
print(cdict['ZS'])
index = -1
for e in cdict['ZS']:
    index += 1
    print("Index:",index, "item", e)
```